# SQL comparison operations

Tags: sql

How do comparison operators in SQL work internally? If I am comparing a particular tuple with a subquery for example using the equal to operator, then is the tuple compared with the *full set* that is the result of the subquery? **Or** the tuple is compared with *each tuple* in the subquery one by one?

Comment: In databases that support tuples, the comparison is to each row in the result set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  
Basically
 there are 2 queries.
 
query1 : sID *<> any* ( select sID from Apply where major = 'EE' )

 query2 : *not* sID = *any* (select sID from Apply where major = 'EE'). What is the difference between query1 and query2?

Answer (score 0):

Following your commentaries:

```
sID <> any ( select sID from Apply where major = 'EE' )
```

Vs

```
not sID = any (select sID from Apply where major = 'EE')
```

`NOT` negates the following condition so is the same for both examples but <> follows ANSI [standard](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~len/sql1999.pdf)